# On regular closed sets which are not open-closed

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra, descriptive-set-theory

Let $Z=2^\omega$ be the Cantor space, $C(Z)$ the field of open-closed subsets of $Z$, and $RC(Z)$ the complete Boolean algebra of **regular closed** subsets of $Z$. It is known that $RC(Z)$ is a minimal completion of $C(Z)$.

I am interested in finding out more about the sets in $RC(Z)\setminus C(Z)$. I guess the simple answer is that they are precisely the regular closed sets which are not open-closed. Moreover, since every open-closed set is regular closed, and open-closed sets form a Boolean algebra, I can safely infer that the sets in $RC(Z)\setminus C(Z)$ are built out of infinite operations.

For example, let $\{B_i\}$ be an arbitrary family of open-closed sets. Then the the denumerable union $\bigcup_i B_i$ is open but not open-closed, and the closure of $\bigcup_i B_i$ is regular closed but still not open-closed unless ${\rm cl}\big(\bigcup_i B_i\big)$ is open, which is of course not true in general. Hence ${\rm cl}\ \big(\bigcup_i B_i\big)$ is an example of a regular closed set which is not open-closed.

(1) Are there other types of **regular closed sets** which are not open-closed?

(2) Also, are the sets in $RC(Z)\setminus C(Z)$ meagre?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed a regular closed set $C$ is of the form $C= \overline{O}$ where $O$ is open in the Cantor space $Z$. As the clopen sets from a countable base for $Z$, we can write $O$ as $\cup_{ n \in \omega} B_n$, where the $B_n$ are clopen. 
So indeed $C  =\overline{\cup_n B_n}$ or $C = \bigvee \{B_n : n \in \omega \}$, using the Boolean operation in $RC(Z)$, i.e. $C$ is the supremum of the clopen family. This observation is part of the proof that $RC(Z)$ is a (minimal) completion of $C(Z)$, namely we reach all elements of $RC(Z)$ as suprema of (of course at most countable, as $C(Z)$ is countable) families from $C(Z)$.

If $C$ is regular closed, so $C = \overline{\operatorname{int}(C)}$. If $C$ were meagre, then so would $\operatorname{int}(C)$ be (as a subset) and the only open and meagre set of $Z$ is the empty set, so then $C = \emptyset$. So **all** members of $RC(Z)\setminus C(Z)$ are non-meagre.

Comment: So, I take it that it is true that non-clopen regular closed sets are closures of countable unions of clopen sets, and that they are the sole elements of $RC(Z)\setminus C(Z)$. But that it is not true that non-clopen regular closed sets are meager. This last point seems strange to me for I thought that countable sets in the Cantor space were meager (because $Z$ is Frechet and perfect). What do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Curious a countable set is never regular closed in $Z$, so I see no contradiction.

Comment: @Curious meagre sets do not play a special role, they don't exist in $C(X)$ nor $RC(X)$. You're confused with another completion, namely the Baire sets of $Z$ modulo the meagre sets.

Comment: Thanks @Henno for coming back with additional thoughts. Can I ask you why a countable set is never regular closed in $Z$? Also, to be sure, the Baire sets you are referring to are just the Borel sets, right? (Because $Z$ is second-countable.)

Comment: @Curious A countable set has empty interior (as all open sets in $Z$ are the same size as $Z$, continuum) and a regular closed set must be the closure of its interior. And Baire sets are the sets with the Baire property, i.e. sets that differ with an open set by a meagre set. This is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the Borel sets but is larger. You get confused because if you mod out the meagre sets, you have essentially the same classes.

Comment: @Curious Meagre sets are not all Borel, so it makes no sense to talk about Borel modded out by meagre sets. Meagre sets are all Baire so inside the Baire algebra we can do a quotient Boolean algebra with the ideal of meagres.

Comment: Ah, I see, it is just that we were not talking about the same thing, for I define Baire sets as the sets belonging to the sigma-field generated by the open-closed sets, whereas you were talking about the Baire sets as the sets with the Baire property.

Comment: @Curious that’s a very non-standard definition. There is another Baire sigma-algebra used in measure theory: the sigma-algebra generated by the closed $G_\delta$ sets. For metric spaces this is just the Borel sigma-algebra but in general it can be smaller, like your definition. Why do you define it like that?

Comment: It is from Halmos's Lectures on Boolean algebras.

Comment: @Curious only in the context of Stone spaces I suppose?

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose so. However, to come back to your explanation "A countable set has empty interior (as all open sets in $Z$ are the same size as $Z$, continuum) and a regular closed set must be the closure of its interior." How does this explain that a countable set is never regular closed in Z? (please, forgive my ignorance)